# Python "AttributeError" for instance declared in __init__

Tags: python, oop, qtimer

I'm developping an application in Python and Qt and there is something that I'd like to clarify.  Take this code example:

```
import serial

from PySide.QtGui import QMainWindow
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import QTimer
from ZumaUI import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    '''
    MainWindow: this is the class that manages all the functionality.
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        '''
        Default Constructor. It can receive a top window as parent. 
        '''
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.serial = serial.Serial()
        self.serial.port = 'COM1'
        self.serial.baudrate = 19200
        self.serial.timeout = 0.5   #make sure that the alive event can be checked from time to time

        self.on_PortSettings()

        self.timer = QTimer(self)            
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.OnRefresh)
        self.timer.start(150)

        self.on_PortSettings()

    def OnRefresh(self):
        pass

    def on_PortSettings(self):
        self.serial.close()
        self.timer.stop()
```

When I run my code, I get

```
"AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'timer'"
```

But I don't have this kind of error for `self.serial` which is called all over within the class.  What is the difference between these two instances and how should I call `timer` so it can be accessed throughout the class?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow! Usually, you will want to post the full traceback, this will make it easier to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `onPortSettings` before you set up `timer`.

```
    self.on_PortSettings() <-- here

    self.timer = QTimer(self)
```

Comment: Oh my!  I was looking for dark OOP concepts that I didn't understand but it turned to be quite easy!  I guess the tree was hiding the forest.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    self.timer = None
```

...

```
def on_PortSettings(self):
    self.serial.close()
    if self.timer is not None:
        self.timer.stop()
```